# getting this error: "The remote server returned an error: (422) Unprocessable Entity." when doing post from C# to RoR

Tags: c#, post, outlook

This code is for an outlook plugin. We're trying to POST to a page and are getting this error:

```
The remote server returned an error: (422) Unprocessable Entity.
```

The C# code is here:

```
webClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        ASCIIEncoding asciiEncoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
        Byte[] postData = asciiEncoding.GetBytes("email=e2@email.com&password=hunter2");
        char[] resultHTML = asciiEncoding.GetChars(webClient.UploadData("http://url", "POST", postData));
        string convertedResultHTML = new string(resultHTML);
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Because of its limited functionality, I avoid using `WebClient` and use `WebRequest` instead.   The code below:

1. does not expect an HTTP 100 status code to be returned,
2. creates a `CookieContainer` to store any cookies we pick up,
3. sets the *Content Length* header, and
4. `UrlEncode`s each value in the post data.

Give the following a try and see if it works for you.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
System.Net.CookieContainer cookies = new System.Net.CookieContainer();

// this first request just ensures we have a session cookie, if one exists
System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/test.aspx");
((System.Net.HttpWebRequest)req).CookieContainer = cookies;
req.GetResponse().Close();

// this request submits the data to the server
req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/test.aspx");
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
req.Method = "POST";
((System.Net.HttpWebRequest)req).CookieContainer = cookies;

string parms = string.Format("email={0}&password={1}", 
    System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("e2@email.com"),
    System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("hunter2"));
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(parms);
req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

// perform the POST
using (System.IO.Stream os = req.GetRequestStream()) 
{
   os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}

// read the response
string response;
using (System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse())
{
  if (resp == null) return;
  using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
  {
      response = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
  }
}
// the variable response holds the results of the request...
```

Credits: [Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HTTPPOSTsAndHTTPGETsWithWebClientAndCAndFakingAPostBack.aspx), [Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938330/httpwebrequest-response-produces-http-422-why/2939727#2939727) (SO Question)

Answer (score 1):

This is the RoR application telling you that you have not formed a request that it can handle; the destination script exists (otherwise you'd see a 404), the request is being handled (otherwise you'd get a 400 error) and it's been encoded correctly (or you'd get a 415 error) but the actual instruction can't be carried out.

Looking at it, you seem to be loading some email information. The RoR application could be telling you that the username and password is wrong, or that the user doesn't exist, or something else. It's up to the RoR application itself.

I think the code itself is good; it's just that the app at the other end isn't happy about doing what you ask it. Are you missing something else in the request information, like a command? (eg `command=getnetemails&email=e2@email.com&password=hunter2`) Are you sure the email/password combination you are passing is good?

see [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2) for more on the 422 error.

Answer (score 1):

POST data must be encoded prior to be sent out on the wire as ASCII, if you are sending character not in the ASCII range. You should try something like:

```
Byte[] postData = asciiEncoding.GetBytes(HttpUtility.UrlEncode("email=e2@email.com&password=hunter2"));
```

Comment: you should encode the value of each parameter individually

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line above your code.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
```

Are you trying to access an authentication required page?

Comment: i added that but i still get the same error. i'm accessing a ruby on rails controller that does nothing but get posted to by the outlook plugin and render some text. there's no logic involved at all.

Answer (score 0):

it was solved by returning xml instead of just unstructured text on the RoR side

Comment: How does an error processing the request get solved by changing how the response is structured?  I'd have expected your app to return a 500 error.